# Error code: 135 - ECONNREFUSED when calling npm run protractor in package.json

Tags: npm, protractor, package.json, npm-run

I am trying to add some scripts to `package.json` to run *Protractor* tests:

```json
"scripts": {
    "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=84.0.4147.30",
    "protractor": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor configuration.js",
    "start": "npm run webdriver-update &&npm run webdriver-start"
}
```

If I open 2 command prompts & run `npm run start` & `npm run protractor`, my tests run fine.

In the tutorial I am following, they are able to just run `npm run protractor` & the tests also run.

However, when I try that then I get this error message:

```
protractor configuration.js
[21:01:19] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:01:19] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[21:01:21] E/launcher - Error code: 135
[21:01:21] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
[21:01:21] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Can someone please tell me why this isn't working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webdriver-manager must run in a separate terminal and then you must start the test.

Run `npm run webdriver-start` in one terminal and let it run.

Later run `npm run protractor` in another terminal to start the tests.